# I have an array of zeros and I want to add 1's to some array elements

Tags: fortran

I tried this in fortran.

The initial array is zeros, for example:

```
InitialMatrix = 0 0 
                0 0 
                0 0
                0 0
```

And I want to add numbers 1 sequentially:

```
FinalMatrix  =  0 0
                0 1
                1 0
                1 1
```

As if adding one bit at a time.

I generated a matrix containing all elements equal to zero and tried to use ibset to change the zero element to 1, but without success.

The code I made was this one:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer(1) numSitio
    integer:: Comb
    integer:: i, j
    integer, dimension(10, 10)::MatrixZeros
    integer, dimension(10, 10)::MatrixSpins
    
    print*, "Set the number of sites: "
    read(*,*)numSitio
    
    Comb = 2**numSitio
    
    MatrixZeros = 0
    MatrixSpins = ibset(MatrixZeros, 1)
        

    do i = 1, Comb
        do j = 1, numSitio
            MatrixSpins(i,j) = 0
        end do
    end do

    do i = 1, Comb
        write(*,*)(MatrixSpins(i,j), j= 1, numSitio)
    end do

    
    !write(*,*)MatrixZeros
    
end program test
```

I generated a matrix of zeros to be auxiliary, and then I created the matrix of spins that I want. I tried using the ibset command to add numbers 1 to zero array.

Note: I want to generate a matrix with n columns and 2^n rows, where the first row is all zero elements and starting from the second row, add a 1 bit in the last column. In the third line, the rightmost bit (last column, move to the left column and go on adding bits 1 until in the last line of the matrix, all elements are 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.
How did you get from Initial array to final? why it is not 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1? why did you start calling it matrix? Maybe delete the question and start again...

Comment: Why are you using `ibset` to add 1 to zero??

Comment: Are you just trying to write out the first `2^n` binary numbers?  And if not that, perhaps explain a bit further what is the objective of the matrix manipulations you are working on.  This smells of being an x-y problem.

Comment: I have an array of 0 and I want to add 1 elements as per the picture.

https://scontent.fcgr2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/317484367_3363980637169975_7741333151547853573_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=dbeb18&_nc_eui2=AeGhE7kPqtFs5CMdPpPcv8VxSU8Rl6D9z9dJTxGXoP3P14j6nqeVhdUCcye-3-TBVCXXa9OMzoPouGe3sMpZr1KM&_nc_ohc=MoCai9sSbQEAX8nMds3&tn=aDf2OWMDUSmMoBGB&_nc_ht=scontent.fcgr2-1.fna&oh=00_AfBwMF8t_fAFIIN02g_zcUsGOYgVOO8_tD788A-UlRU4Jw&oe=638A66A2

Comment: You could use iand to set appropriate elements of your matrix, rather than ibset. Or you could do the traditional "carry" operations to generate each row from the preceding one. But do you need to put your results (for the first few binary numbers) in a matrix? What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you just confirm you are trying to count in binary? I don't really see how the code you have relates to the "pictures" above. If this is the case I'll vote to reopen. And I agree with @HighPerformanceMark , what are you really trying to do?

Comment: This, I'm trying to count in binary.

Comment: *I'm trying to count in binary*.  Yes, but what do you want your computer program to do?  It is easy to code a loop which will write out binary numbers in sequence, `0000, 0001, 0010, 0011,...` - just write a `do` loop from `1,n` and write the number in binary (use the `b` edit descriptor).  If you just want to write a sequence of binary numbers to the screen, no need for any arrays, no need for`ibset` or its related functions, ....

Comment: I was trying to do what I asked here on the forum and I finally got it, but I saw that it was a lot of work. Using the tip given by @High Performance Mark to create a loop and use the b descriptor I got it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to count in binary, then just

```
program test
   implicit none
   integer i, n
   character fmt

   print *, "Input number of bits: ";   read *, n
   write( fmt, "( i0 )" ) n
   print "( b0." // fmt // " )", ( i, i = 0, 2 ** n - 1 )

end program test
```

If you absolutely have to store all the configurations in a matrix (an array of characters would be just as good) then you can just count up with traditional "carry" operations:

```
program test
   implicit none
   integer i, j, imx, jmx
   integer n
   integer, allocatable :: M(:,:)

   print *, "Input number of bits: ";   read *, n
   imx = 2 ** n - 1;   jmx = n - 1
   allocate( M(0:imx, 0:jmx) )
   M = 0

   do i = 1, imx
      M(i,:) = M(i-1,:)
      M(i,jmx) = M(i,jmx) + 1
      j = jmx
      do while ( M(i,j) > 1 )     ! "carry" operations
         M(i,j) = 0
         j = j - 1
         M(i,j) = M(i,j) + 1
      end do
   end do

   do i = 0, imx
      print "( *( i1, 1x ) )", M(i,:)
   end do

end program test
```

or you could use bit operations:

```
program test
   implicit none
   integer i, j, imx, jmx, p
   integer n
   integer, allocatable :: M(:,:)

   print *, "Input number of bits: ";   read *, n
   imx = 2 ** n - 1;   jmx = n - 1
   allocate( M(0:imx, 0:jmx) )
   M = 0

   p = 1
   do j = 0, jmx
      do i = 0, imx
         if ( iand(i,p) > 0 ) M(i,jmx-j) = 1
      end do
      p = 2 * p
   end do

   do i = 0, imx
      print "( *( i1, 1x ) )", M(i,:)
   end do

end program test
```